# Simple factory call giving error in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

In a simple example, I am expecting console to ping me "USA". Instead I am getting an error. Can someone help fix it?

**SNIPPET:**

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
</head> 

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<script>
//module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, myFactory){
    var a = myFactory();
    console.log(a.country);
});

//factory declaration
app.factory('myFactory',function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.country = "USA";
    return obj;
});
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script> 


<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<script>
//module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, myFactory){
    var a = myFactory;
    console.log(a.country);
});

app.factory('myFactory',function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.country = "USA";
    return obj;
});
</script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the runtime is telling you, myFactory is not a function.

```
var a = myFactory();
```

This call is therefore not valid. You can do this.

```
var a = myFactory;
console.log(a.country);
```

Or just:

```
console.log(myFactory.country);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html> 
<head> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
</head> 

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<script>
//module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
//controller declaration
//factory declaration
app.factory('myFactory',function(){
    var obj = {};


    return {
        get: function(){
           obj.country = "USA";
            return obj;
        },

    }
});

app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, myFactory){
    var a = myFactory.get();
    console.log(a.country);
});

</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the alternate way with `$injector`

```
//module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, $injector){
    var a = $injector.get('myFactory')
    console.log(a.country);
});

//factory declaration
app.factory('myFactory',function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.country = "USA";
    return obj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because the factory returns a service object and you're trying to invoke it as a function.

Check the below code snippet.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController)
  .factory('demoFactory', demoFactory);

DefaultController.$inject = ['demoFactory'];

function DefaultController(demoFactory) {
  console.log(demoFactory.country);
}

function demoFactory() {
  var service = {
    country: 'USA'
  };
  
  return service;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl"></div>
</div>
```